# How to solve "Unresolved Reference" Kotlin Function

Tags: function, kotlin, compiler-errors, function-declaration

I was trying to build the following programme:

```
open class Phone(var isScreenLightOn: Boolean = false){
    open fun switchOn() {
        isScreenLightOn = true
    }

    open fun switchOff() {
        isScreenLightOn = false
    }

    open fun checkPhoneScreenLight() {
        var phoneScreenLight = if (isScreenLightOn) "on" else "off"
        println("The phone screen's light is $phoneScreenLight.")
    }
}

   class FoldablePhone (var folded: Boolean = true): Phone() {
    
    fun fold (){
        if (folded == false){
            folded = true
            println(folded)
            isScreenLightOn = false
        }
        else {
            println(folded)
        }
    }
    
    fun unfold (){
        if (folded == true){
            folded = false
            println(folded)
        }
        else {
            println(folded)
        }
    }
    
    override fun switchOn(){
        if (folded == false){
            isScreenLightOn = true
            checkPhoneScreenLight()
        }
        else {
            println("Phone folded")
        }
    }
    
}

fun main()
{
    var phone: Phone = FoldablePhone()
    phone.fold()
    phone.switchOn()
    phone.unfold()
}
```

When compiling, errors saying "Unresolved Reference" for the phone.fold() and phone.unfold() in the main() are coming up. I looked online and found no help as people are saying that the function in question should be declared, when in actual fact I did so. How can I solve this please?

Comment: Why did you declare `phone` to be of type `Phone`? That makes `fold` and `unfold` available. It would have worked if it is of type `FoldablePhone`, i.e. `val phone = FoldablePhone()`.

Comment: I thought that I had to write it that way since FoldablePhone has an IS A relationship with Phone.

Comment: You *can* write it like that, and allow `phone` to store other kinds of phones, but you don't *have to* write it like that.

Comment: Noted. I followed your advice found in your first comment and the compiler ran the program without issues. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared your variable `phone` to be of type `Phone`. But the `fold` and `unfold` functions are only available on the subtype `FoldablePhone`. Therefore they are not accessible.

Instead of:

`var phone: Phone = FoldablePhone()`

you can use:

`var phone: FoldablePhone = FoldablePhone()`

or shorter, because Kotlin can infer the type:

`var phone = FoldablePhone()`

Alternatively, you can check the type before using the `fold/unfold` functions:

```
if (phone is FoldablePhone) phone.fold()
```

This uses a "[smart cast](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/typecasts.html#smart-casts)" i.e. the Kotlin compiler knows that inside the `if` the `phone` variable is a `FoldablePhone` and automatically casts it to that type.

This alternative approach becomes more useful in real programs where a function may operate on a type of `Phone`, and it has to conditionally execute the fold/unfold functions.